# How to bind i18next translate method to a grunt-contrib-pug compiler

Tags: javascript, express, gruntjs, internationalization, i18next

I'm having trouble to bind i18next translate method to the grunt-pug-i18n task.

I'm using Node.js, Express.js and Pug on a website with i18next and i18next-express-middleware for internationalisation.

Therefore I use this function on the pug templates to find a translation :

```
=t('key') // or #{t('key')}
```

Then for the needs of a static version I'm using grunt-pug-i18n in a grunt task to compile the website into html. But the basic use would need me to replace the t method in the templates by a namespace like this :

```
#{$i18n.key}
```

Works fine but it breaks the dynamic version.

**I need a solution to make both dynamic and static worlds work the same way.**

So I tried to get grunt-pug-i18n to work with the t('key') method.

Using this issue https://github.com/AdesisNetlife/grunt-pug-i18n/issues/21, it looks like I can bind the i18n.t method to the options.data so the task can understand the t method in the templates :

```
// instantiate i18next
var i18n = require('i18next');
i18n.init({
  lng: 'en',
  resources: {
    en: {
      translation: grunt.file.readJSON( webDir + 'locales/en/translation.json' )
    }
  }
});
console.log(i18n.t('key'));//works fine

...

// grunt task
pug: {
  compile: {
    options: {
      namespace   : 'JST',
      separator   : '\n\n',
      amd         : false,
      client      : false,
      pretty      : true,
      self        : false,
      debug       : false,
      compileDebug: true,
      //i18n specific options
      i18n: {
        locales: webDir + 'locales/en/translation.json'
      },
      //supposedly bind the i18n.t method to the task
      data: function() {
        return {
          t: i18n.t
        };
      }
    },
    files: [ {
      cwd: webDir + 'views',
      src: ['**/*.pug', '!**/_*.pug'],
      dest: webDir + 'static',
      expand: true,
      ext: '.htm'
    } ]
  }
}
```

It looks like the binding is done but I end up with this error :

```
>> TypeError: website/views/_layout.pug:9
>>     7|     meta( name='description' content='' )
>>     8|     meta( name='author' content='' )
>>   > 9|     title=t('title')
>>     10|   
>> Cannot read property 'translator' of undefined
```

**How to bind the i18next translation method to a grunt-contrib-pug task ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
//supposedly bind the i18n.t method to the task
data: function() {
  return {
    t: i18n.t
  };
}
```

try

```
//supposedly bind the i18n.t method to the task
data: function() {
  return {
    t: i18n.t.bind(i18n)
  };
}
```

see more here:
https://github.com/i18next/i18next-express-middleware/blob/master/src/index.js#L33

Comment: It's better as it doesn't throw an error message anymore. but it translates with the key instead of the translation.

**t('section.about.h2')** gives section.about.h2 instead of the translation

Comment: Mh, thats strange.
Outputting just the key is the default behaviour if a translation for the given key could not be found.
I'm doing it this way in an app using jade templates as well.
Does it work in your dev tools console?
Had similar problems at first but it was my fault as I was accesing translations before the translation ressource was fully loaded

Comment: You are right I replaced **grunt.file.read()** by **grunt.file.readJSON()** in the i18next instantiation to get the translation file and it works perfectly.